# compare div ID to JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to compare and make equal an element div `id` I receive from an jQuery `post` request to a `json` file object. The proble is that whenever I return my object, I get it as `{ 'fruits': ' '}` and it's not equal to the `id`.

> Trying to compare div ID to Json object and make them equal. I receive my id as `fruits` and my json object as `{ 'fruits': ' '}`. How can I make them equal?

Here is my post request:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
                $(document).on('click', '#themap', function (e) {
                    var fruit_value = e.target.id;
                    console.log(map_value);
                        $.ajax({
                            'type':'POST',
                            'data':fruit_value,
                            'url': '/something',
                            'timeout': 1000,
                            'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                if(textStatus==="timeout") {
                                   console.log("The POST JQUERY Function has timed out.")
                                }
                            },
                            'success': function(data){
                                console.log("I've successfully passed the", data);
                            }
                        });
                });
            });
```

Here is my NodeJS back end:

```
app.post('/something', isLoggedIn,function(req, res, next){
            var fruit_value = req.body;
            console.log("front end request element ===>", fruit_value);

    fs.readFile('views/pages/json/fruits.json', 'utf8', function(err, data){
                    if (err) throw err; 
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);

                      console.log(obj[0].id);
                    if (obj[0].id == fruit_value){
                        console.log("CHA CHING");
                    }else{
                        console.log("Values are not the same ===>", fruit_value);
                    }

                });    
     });
```

Comment: Without seeing some relevant snippet of `fruits.json` we can't really help.  It could be something as simple as incorrect JSON.  It would also really help to see the output from the `console.log()` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use id as key as below :

```
var id = 'fruits',
    obj = {'fruits': ''};

   if (obj[id] !== undefined){
       // fruits exists
   }
```